# Can this date time function be written more efficiently?

Tags: datetime, coldfusion

The following function returns the difference between two date time values in words (as a string). Can it be written more efficiently/elegantly?

```
/**
* @hint Returns the difference between two time strings in words.
*/
public string function timeAgoInWords(required date fromTime, date toTime=now())
{
    local.secondDiff = dateDiff("s", arguments.fromTime, arguments.toTime);

    if (local.secondDiff <= 60)
        return "#local.secondDiff# seconds ago";

    local.minuteDiff = dateDiff("n", arguments.fromTime, arguments.toTime);

    if (local.minuteDiff <= 60)
        if (local.minuteDiff < 2)
            return "1 minute ago";
        else return "#local.minuteDiff# minutes ago";

    if (local.minuteDiff <= 1440)
        if (local.minuteDiff <= 120)
            return "1 hour ago";
        else return "#int(local.minuteDiff/60)# hours ago";

    if (local.minuteDiff <= 2880)
        return "yesterday";

    if (local.minuteDiff <= 4320)
        return "2 days ago";

    local.monthDiff = dateDiff("m", arguments.fromTime, arguments.toTime);

    if (local.monthDiff <= 12)
        return "#dateFormat(arguments.fromTime, "mmm dd")# at #timeFormat(arguments.fromTime, "h:mm")#";

    return "#dateFormat(arguments.fromTime, "mmm dd 'yy")# at #timeFormat(arguments.fromTime, "h:mm")#";
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's more efficient, but someone already wrote a UDF that does this very thing: http://cflib.org/udf/ago

Comment: @Al, thanks... it looks a but weird using a loop though... doesn't it make more sense to write something along the lines of what I wrote? What's the value in the loop?

Comment: oh btw, by default u don't need @hint at all.

Comment: @Henry, thanks. I prefer to have it. Does it have any impact on the function at all?

Comment: no impact whether u use @hint or not... just less typing and cleaner especially when all you have in the block is a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I wrote a few months ago, based on the UDF Al Everett posted above in the comment and written in CF9 script style.  It won't be more efficient.  In fact, it should be slower then your implementation 'cause it has multiple calls to `dateDiff()`, and needs to set up 2 arrays up front, but the overall line count is shorter and easily understandable.

```
string function ago(required Date dateThen)
{
    var dateparts = ["yyyy","m","d","h","n"];
    var datepartNames = ["year","month","day","hour","minute"];
    var rightNow = Now();

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)    // 5 == arrayLen(dateparts)
    {
        var diff = dateDiff(variables.dateparts[i], dateThen, rightNow);

        if (diff > 1)
            return "#diff# #datepartNames[i]#s ago";

        if (diff == 1)
            return "#diff# #datepartNames[i]# ago";
    }

    return "Just Now";
}
```

Comment: thanks, that looks good. The function will be called roughly 50 times per page, so perhaps it's a better approach to do without the arrays? Much cleaner, readably approach, though. Thanks for the example.

Comment: @Mohamad, if you prefer, you may put that UDF into a CFC, and cache the 2 arrays in the Variables scope.  Then put the Singleton CFC in your Application scope.

Answer (score 2):

It looks good to me. You could instead use your first diff (local.secondDiff) for all your tests rather than re-diffing, but this is probably easier to read.